# Smoothing overlapping spheres

Tags: modeling

I have three spheres that overlap to form an eyeball shape and the seams looks terrible. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using three separate spheres, use one sphere and extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]